# searching a pattern in string and storing its values

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml in string format. I want to get the attribute called "ColumnName". Please help me with finding and returning it in array. Bellow is the format

```
<EntitySet Name="Department" VersionConflict="False"  xmlns:">

<StringAttribute Caption="Department Number" ColumnName="fdeptno" Description="dept no" IsPrimaryKeyMember="True" IsRequired="True" MaxLength="2" Name="fdeptno" RequiredAdherenceMessage="EMPTY_ACCT(Department Number)" />
<StringAttribute Caption="Description" ColumnName="fdeptdesc" Description="department" IsRequired="True" MaxLength="35" Name="fdeptdesc" RequiredAdherenceMessage="DESCR_EMPTY" />
<StringAttribute Caption="Holiday Pay Acct" ColumnName="fholaccno" ContentType="GeneralLedgerAccount" Description="holiday" IsRequired="True" MaxLength="25" Name="fholaccno" RequiredAdherenceMessage="HOLIDAY_PAY_ACC">
  <StringAttribute.Format>
    <MaskFormat Mask="AAAAA-AA" />
  </StringAttribute.Format>
  <PropertyReference EntityName="glmast" Filter="GLMAST.flinactive=0" Name="prdept_fholaccno" ObjectName="ChartofAccountsMaintenance" PropertyName="fcacctnum" UseIndexView="True" />
</StringAttribute>
<StringAttribute Caption="Other Pay Acct" ColumnName="fothaccno" ContentType="GeneralLedgerAccount" Description="other" IsRequired="True" MaxLength="25" Name="fothaccno" RequiredAdherenceMessage="OTHER_PAY_EMPTY">
  <StringAttribute.Format>
    <MaskFormat Mask="AAAAA-AA" />
  </StringAttribute.Format>
  <PropertyReference EntityName="glmast" Filter="GLMAST.flinactive=0" Name="prdept_fothaccno" ObjectName="ChartofAccountsMaintenance" PropertyName="fcacctnum" UseIndexView="True" />
</StringAttribute>
<StringAttribute Caption="Sick Pay Acct" ColumnName="fsickaccno" ContentType="GeneralLedgerAccount" Description="sick" IsRequired="True" MaxLength="25" Name="fsickaccno" RequiredAdherenceMessage="SICK_PAY_EMPTY">
  <StringAttribute.Format>
    <MaskFormat Mask="AAAAA-AA" />
  </StringAttribute.Format>
  <PropertyReference EntityName="glmast" Filter="GLMAST.flinactive=0" Name="prdept_fsickaccno" ObjectName="ChartofAccountsMaintenance" PropertyName="fcacctnum" UseIndexView="True" />
</StringAttribute>
<StringAttribute Caption="Vacation Pay Acct" ColumnName="fvacaccno" ContentType="GeneralLedgerAccount" Description="vacation" IsRequired="True" MaxLength="25" Name="fvacaccno" RequiredAdherenceMessage="VAC_PAY_ACCT_EMPTY">
  <StringAttribute.Format>
    <MaskFormat Mask="AAAAA-AA" />
  </StringAttribute.Format>
  <PropertyReference EntityName="glmast" Filter="GLMAST.flinactive=0" Name="prdept_fvacaccno" ObjectName="ChartofAccountsMaintenance" PropertyName="fcacctnum" UseIndexView="True" />
</StringAttribute>
<IntegerAttribute ColumnName="identity_column" Name="identity_column" />
<ByteArrayAttribute ColumnName="timestamp_column" Name="timestamp_column" Searchable="False" />
<StringAttribute Caption="facility" ColumnName="fac" Description="facility" MaxLength="20" Name="fac" />
```

Comment: Which of the many `ColumnName`'s?

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried?

Comment: That's not valid XML, by the way. `<EntitySet ...>` is not closed, and there's an unmatched quote in the first tag.

Comment: It is fetched from a function which comes this way. I agree its not closed properly. But I want some solution how I can parse this from that variable and get all values of ColumnName in the above string.

Comment: @ShishirKumarM The right solution depends on whether the input is valid XML or not. Is it?

Comment: @ShishirKumarM: You can't ask for a solution or "give me some code". You have to try something first and if it doesn't work, then ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOMParser) to parse the string. Then, you can loop through all elements and check the attributes. I prefer to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) though, because the resulting code is concise and effective:

```
var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xml_string, 'text/xml');
var elementsWithAttr = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('[ColumnName]');
var values = [].map.call(elementsWithAttr, function(element) {
    return element.attributes.getNamedItem('ColumnName').nodeValue;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hm3Cn/ (I've taken your XML input, made it valid by removing `xmlns:"` at the first line, and appending `</EntitySet>` at the end).

Comment: so this line return element.attributes.getNamedItem('ColumnName').nodeValue; should be altered to make the value store in array format

Comment: @ShishirKumarM No, `values` is already an array. If you look at the [demo in my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/hm3Cn/), you'll see an array being logged in the console. `[].map.call( <array-like object>, <callback function>)` creates an array based on the return values of executing `<callback function>` for each element in the array-like object.